# What requests “/adform/IFrameManager.html”

Tags: windows, ads

I'm currently running a live-beta-test with my new application and I see some requests towards /adform/IFrameManager.html

What makes these requests towards my site?

Is it maybe Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

It's an AdForm configuration request for Google's DoubleClick Ad Exchange Real-Time Bidding Protocol.

-- https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/expandables#vendor